# Universal Electronic Car Aerial

Tags: arduino, mosfet, switches, control

[image]I was wondering if there anybody out there that might be able to help me. I am trying to control an electronic car aerial with an Arduino using Mosfet switches however the circuit I have built doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone tried something like this before or know of a good walkthrough to accomplish this?

The help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No circuit, specifications, technical info so you leave us guessing. => Close !

Comment: You need to post a schematic of what you have done.  Without that, all we can do is guess.

Comment: That is the best I can do with the editor atm

Comment: Which Arduino outputs are you using?  Are those digital or PWM?

Comment: They are digital pins

Comment: Are the 12V ground and 5V ground properly connected? Does applying the 5V to the gate of the motor transistor turn on the motor?

Answer (score 3):

Power car antennas typically have 3 wires. One is ground, one is constant +12 and one is switched to +12 or open. Color codes vary.

You need a *high side switch* to switch the controlled line.

When the high side switch is active (+12 on that wire) the antenna mast goes up until it hits the upper limit switch. When the controlled wire is low or open, the mast goes down until it hits the lower limit switch (power is supplied through the +12 always-on).

Edit: Example high-side switch. Note that the MOSFET is a P-channel type. The diode D1 and R1 are to protect the MOSFET gate from transients on the 12V line. Q1 level shifts the input from CMOS/TTL level to 12V. Input high turns Q1 on, pulling the gate of M1 low and turning it on, which energizes the grounded load. D2 is to deal with inductive loads.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB4gQ2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: And would a high side switch have the capability of turning off midway to leave the actual antenna half way extended?

I would like to be able to close it, open it and stop it at any point because at the moment its either fully out or in.

Comment: To do that you'd have to break the constant +12, with another high side switch (or you could fiddle with the GND). Otherwise it will just run up or down with nothing inbetween (as it is designed to do).

Comment: Are MOSFETS not High Side Switches? If its not too much to ask would you be able to send a schematic diagram?

Comment: +1, because I learned about car antennas. With your answer, OPs symbold suddenly makes more sense (I was wondering why I did not see a typical DC motor with 2 connections with a H bridge).